# Multi-page django form - slider or FormWizard?

Tags: django, css, django-forms, django-formwizard

I have a long form that I want to break into multiple pages.

I am evaluating between two options for presentation:

1. Present the form on multiple pages using the [FormWizard](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/)
2. Present the form on a slider like [CSS3 slider](http://csscience.com/responsiveslidercss3/).

The slider is actually just one page long using CSS3 to give impression of slides. It floats all of the content areas next to each other, hides the overflow, sets page `width` to say 500% if we have 5 slides, and moves the left-margin -100% to show the next slide. So it is all one page but seems like the form is being shown on sliding pages.

To me the advantage of slider approach is that there is only one form and the user submits the form only once at the end of slides and thus can go back and forth to make changes.(This is will be a common case).

Versus having mini-Forms for `FormWizard` and submitting them after each page. To me, `FormWizards` seems complicated especially if the user wants to change any of previous page responses. I also need `FileField` on my form pages and it seems like `FormWizard` accepts `FileField` only on the last page.

However, I have not seen many folks use this sliding forms (CSS3 or JScript one) approach. Hence, as  a newbie, I am wondering if there are some obvious pitfalls of doing this?

Comment: In case anyone is interested, we have been using CSS Slider with single form for many months now and so far its been a smooth ride.

Answer (score 1):

I can only write about `FormWizard` as I have used it before. According to 'Handling Files' section of Django documentation which can be found in

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/

a `FileField` can be used in any step of your `FormWizard` implementation. What I found really  helpful by using `FormWizard` from Django, is that it provides you all the standard functionality of `Forms`. That means that you can easily create and manipulate forms, validate fields in each step, etc. I am not aware of how CSS3 slider accomplishes validation, but I guess that validation should take place on client side.

Additionally, Django's `FormWizard` uses either a Cookie storage backend, or a Session storage backend in order to store information, which makes the navigation between steps and modifying previous stored data pretty trivial.

I hope I helped you in your decision! A lot more information can be found of course in the Django documentation of `FormWizard` in the link I provided above.